# cut string between characters and doesn't remove those characters

Tags: java, android, regex

the question is quite easy. I have following Strings

```
String str1 = "<img alt=\"Рейтинг \" src=\"https://itvdn.blob.core.windows.net/images/images-bfa852f3-c227-46dd-86d7-2628f7338b0b.png\">";
String str2 = "<img class=\"w640\" id=\"customHeaderImage\" src=\"http://i067.radikal.ru/1412/23/c71d6e8e7d47.jpg\">";
```

I need to remove string between `img` and `src` and keep them. So the result should look like this:

```
String str1 = "<img src=\"https://itvdn.blob.core.windows.net/images/images-bfa852f3-c227-46dd-86d7-2628f7338b0b.png\">";
String str2 = "<img src=\"http://i067.radikal.ru/1412/23/c71d6e8e7d47.jpg\">";
```

I have already tried:

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("(img)[^&]*(src)", "");
str2 = str2.replaceAll("img.*?src", "");
```

But it removes `img` and `src` as well

For the moment I'm using following solution

```
String firstDelim = "img";
String secondDelim = "src";
int delim1 = str1.indexOf(firstDelim);
int delim2 = str1.indexOf(secondDelim);
if (delim1 >= 0 && delim2 > delim1) {
    str1= str1.substring(0, delim1 + firstDelim.length()) + " " + body.substring(delim2);
}
```

But I think there is another way. Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "lookarounds" for this:

```
String str1 = "<img alt=\"Рейтинг \" src=\"https://itvdn.blob.core.windows.net/images/images-bfa852f3-c227-46dd-86d7-2628f7338b0b.png\">";
String str2 = "<img class=\"w640\" id=\"customHeaderImage\" src=\"http://i067.radikal.ru/1412/23/c71d6e8e7d47.jpg\">";
//                                  | preceded by "img"
//                                  |       | any character, reluctantly quantified
//                                  |       |   | followed by "src"
//                                  |       |   |        | replace with 1 space
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("(?<=img).+?(?=src)", " "));
System.out.println(str2.replaceAll("(?<=img).+?(?=src)", " "));
```

**Output**

```
<img src="https://itvdn.blob.core.windows.net/images/images-bfa852f3-c227-46dd-86d7-2628f7338b0b.png">
<img src="http://i067.radikal.ru/1412/23/c71d6e8e7d47.jpg">
```

**Note**

Markup parsing with regex is never a good idea. In this case though, the replacement is simple enough. But beware edge cases!

Answer (score 2):

Very simple indeed. You are almost there:

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("(img)[^&]*(src)", "img src");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\bimg\b).*?(?=\bsrc\b)
```

Try this.Replace by `space`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/23

For java it would be

```
 (?<=\\bimg\\b).*?(?=\\bsrc\\b)
```

Here we use `0 width assertions` rather than consuming the string itself.

(?<=\bimg\b) `lookbehind to check string to be captured has img before it.`

(?=\bsrc\b) `lookahead to see if string being captured has src ahead of it.`

Comment: Thanks, it works. And thank you for the online regex checker, didnt know about it.

Comment: @MaxZavernutiy yes always play around regexs over there.Its pretty useful and one day you will a pro.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, all of the answers are working. Unfortunately I can't mark all answers as right. I'm using `System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("(?<=img).+?(?=src)", " "));` so marked it as correct.
But I thank guys for all answers, they are really hepful!